# Where can one find a list of players ranked by achievement points?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Is there a site that you can go to that lists out users ranked by achievement? 
Perhaps a way to list them out like that on the StarCraft 2 website?

Comment: I changed it from "Achievement" to "achievement points", because that is what I guessed was meant. If you meant "achievements" (which isn't as readily available to individuals), feel free to edit the question appropriately.

Comment: ah, yes Achievement points is accurate. Thank you for the update.

Comment: I voted to re-open after reading Oak's ideas in the meta.

Comment: For reference, [here's a link to the discussion on meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/869/how-is-this-off-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that SC2Ranks.com has finally added an achievement points list!

http://sc2ranks.com/ach/all/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a website that has done this yet, but one could be made, though it would not be as accurate without the census being available.

Comment: I think you are right, I've contemplated contacting the people at sc2ranks.com and asking how they are gathering their data, and seeing if i can utilize that technique to gather the info about Achievement Points and provide a website of similar worth.

Comment: @jblaske - Not sure if you've seen it yet, but that question was asked recently: [Where do the third party stats sites get their data?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/where-do-the-third-party-stats-sites-get-their-data)

Comment: I did see that, tho I don't believe they are being 100% truthful in that response. That's more than likely the explanation they give so they don't get in trouble for crawling and scraping the battle.net web page. Which is what I'm afraid i might have to do, to accomplish this.