# Where do the third party stats sites get their data?

Tags: starcraft-2

Both sc2ranks.com and rts-sanctuary provide stats on starcraft 2 rankings.  where do they get their data? is it a special deal they have with Blizzard, or are they accessing a public feed that Blizzard supplies, or are they scraping the battlenet web site somehow?

UPDATE:
After reading the post linked to in my comment, maybe a rephrase would appease the masses:
Let me phrase my question as a question about the features of StarCraft 2.  "Does Starcraft II have a feature or API by which a player can download data about match histories for themselves and others?"  Hopefully questions about the features of games are considered on topic :)

ps - in an attempt to find out why people were voting for it to be closed, i accidentally voted to close it myself :).  And now I can't unvote.  oh well.

Comment: Not sure how asking whether blizzard, a game manufacturer, has a feed that supplies statistics about a game, doesn't belong on a gaming Q+A site?

Comment: before anyone else votes to close this, please consider this post, which argues that questions about resources for looking up statistics are on topic:  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/869/how-is-this-off-topic

Comment: I know I originally closed this, but I'm very on the fence about this question...

Answer (score 13):

As stated on [Starcraft 2 Rankings](http://sc2ranks.com/)' [FAQ page](http://sc2ranks.com/faq):

> Blizzard does not provide any easy to use list of players, we rely on cascade spidering through saved players, manually entered players and spidering through Blizzard forums to find players.
>
> If you do not see a character, adding them through the character tab above will queue them and their division.

So they're simply scraping all the data Blizzard *does* supply, however little.

Comment: that sounds like a royal PITA

Comment: It is, yeah. The same goes for most stats websites, including one for BFBC2. At least most SteamWorks games expose the games directly.

Comment: Does not sound like a PITA at all. The programming does all the work. You just input the character and the program does the rest.

Comment: @Doug - I believe that @espais was referring to *programming* the site itself.

Comment: @Doug the programming itself is a pain in the arse indeed, because blizzard can change their markup any minute and it will screw up all the scrapers