# Hi-res Achievement and Trophy Images

Tags: achievements

Hey there. I'm working on an app which uses achievement and trophy images. Are there public APIs (one for PS3 and one for Xbox 360) which I can make use of to get hold of these?

I understand this is only really half related to gaming but would hugely appreciate any assistance.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this

Comment: @Nick This doesn't look like game-dev material. It's gaming development, maybe, but what is being developed isn't a game or a mod to a game, so I think we'd be stretching it for them. To me, it looks like a Gaming Resource question, so I'd keep it open like we did [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/where-can-one-find-a-list-of-players-ranked-by-achievement-points-for-starcraft-2). But if you still think it's off-topic, it might sit on an unusual fence and we could open up a Meta question to see what the community thinks.

Comment: @GraceNote: agreed, definitely not a game development question in my book.

Answer (score 2):

When I wrote a way to pull achievements onto my web page there wasn't an official Xbox Live API (though this may have changed recently).  Instead I found an API that someone had hacked together:

http://duncanmackenzie.net/blog/put-up-a-rest-api-for-xbox-gamertag-data

http://drupal.org/project/xbox_api

It's not currently maintained, and if I remember properly you can't get very large images, but to the best of my knowledge it is the only way to pull data directly from Xbox Live.